# Setting NSLocalizedRecoveryOptionsErrorKey as NSError UserInfo doesn't provide any recovery options

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

Attempting to set some custom buttons for `presentError` via. `NSLocalizedRecoveryOptionsErrorKey` isn't working. Only the standard "OK" button is displayed.

```
NSApp.presentError(NSError(domain: "", code: 0, userInfo: [
    NSLocalizedRecoveryOptionsErrorKey: ["Foo", "Bar"]
]))
```

It also have no effect setting any of the other UserInfo keys.

Is this simply no longer supported on OS X 10.11 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"MyCoolDomain" code:1 userInfo:@{
                          NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: @"Could Not Post Message",
                          NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey: @"We could not reach the XING server. Your internet connection seems to be offline.",
                          NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestionErrorKey: @"You may try again when you are online again.",
                          NSLocalizedRecoveryOptionsErrorKey: @[@"Try again", @"Cancel"]
                      }];
    NSAlert *alert = [NSAlert alertWithError:error];
    alert.informativeText = [error.localizedFailureReason stringByAppendingFormat:@"\n\n%@", alert.informativeText];
    [alert beginSheetModalForWindow:self.view.window completionHandler:^(NSModalResponse returnCode) {
    }];
```

Try this.
source : https://github.com/Hotel-Reservation-Service/HRSCustomErrorHandling/issues/8

When I face issues like these, I go [searching](https://github.com/search?q=NSLocalizedRecoveryOptionsErrorKey&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) for other people's code / issues.

Comment: I'll do as a workaround, thanks. Strange that Apple haven't documented if this changed.